# Convert audio from old video game

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have some audiofiles from an old video game in a very rare format,
`22050 hz, 2 channel, 4 bit, PCM` (not ADPCM).

Is there any tool around to convert that in any modern format?
I tried `ffplay -ac 2 -acodec adpcm_ima_apc -i $audiofile` but that did not work out (it played back, but in a terrible quality)

I uploaded one of the files here (Be sure to use the right download-button, not the one from the add):
https://www.file-upload.net/download-13698824/Morningmood.wav.html

Comment: `ffplay -ac 2 -acodec adpcm_ima_apc -i Morningmood.wav ` worked fine here with your sample file.  Or possibly convert it first and play that instead: `ffmpeg -acodec adpcm_ima_apc -i Morningmood.wav out2.wav` GL!

Comment: It worked somewhat fine, but there is a lot of hiss, especially on the left channel. Ingame the audio is much clearer. I think this is because ```-acodec adpcm_ima_apc``` converts it from adpcm to wave, not from pcm.

Comment: Here's what my ffmpeg converted it into: http://rdp.inet2.org/incoming/out2.mp3 does that match yours?

Comment: does that match yours?